# Random " Being picked up by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am passing an array from php to javascript but it seems to be picking up a extra " at the start and finish of the array.

My array being sent from the PHP file

`json_encode($CheckItems."|".$CheckUserItems."|".$CheckUserMessages."|".$CheckCommentsForproducts."|".$CheckComments);`

My File reciving the array.

```
url: 'CheckServer.php',
success: function(data) {
var DataBaseCheck = (data)
DataBaseCheck = data.split("|");
console.info(DataBaseCheck);
```

Console.info prints `""0","1","2","3""`

When checking if Database[0] matches with anther variable it fails due to the extra " when i console log each array i get `"0,1,2,3"`

How can i solve this i have tried

```
DataBaseCheck.replace('""','"')
DataBaseCheck.replace('"','')
Array1 = parseInt(DataBaseCheck[0])
```

I cannot think of any other way to remove them ??

Comment: I guess it is printing "stringified" json data. Try accessing each member separately and see if you have any data issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "extra double quotes" are there because you have a JSON encoded string.  You are getting JSON from your PHP code, so in your JavaScript the first step should be to decode it:

```
function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    data = data.split("|");
    # data is now an array of strings, e.g. ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Really though, if you are trying to pass an array of integers from your PHP code to your JavaScript code, rather than using your own delimiter you are better off just creating an array in PHP and JSON encoding that, then your JavaScript would just be JSON decoding and you would have the correct data.